# Setting layout constraints for a UIWindow

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Consider the following scenario: I have a **UIWindow** subclass that displays a notification on top while pushing the window down, very similar to what an incoming call does. At the moment, I do all this via setting the windows frame, which works well. However, as I have been using AutoLayout throughout all new projects, I would like to transition this UIWindow class to AutoLayout as well.

The following questions arise:

1. As the UIWindow subclass is the key window, is there anything I could align the constraints to, anyhow?
2. Can I access the constraints of a UIWindow that are created automatically by `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`? `self.constraints` returns an empty Array...

So, in a nutshell: has anybody managed to set layout constraints for a **UIWindow** (not subviews) in relation to the screen? Or is that just not possible and I have to stick to programmatically setting frames?

Comment: Ever find a way to do this?